# Apostrophe cms copied widgets get lots of you were unable to take control errors

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

Most of the time Apostrophe behaves itself until you start to copy widgets or include pieces that have widgets embedded in them. I can't replicate this behaviour on demand but it comes soon enough if I copy a widget using the clone button on the apos control, have a copied widget or I insert a piece that has a bunch of cloned widgets within.

If I refresh the page problem goes away for a while then all of a sudden I can't take control of the document/widget/piece again. (always.js 289) To be clear I am the only one working on the page/widget/piece so it shouldn't be a locking issue although it presents itself as one.

I designed on the basis that widgets can be stacked on other widgets and repeat as often as needed. Widgets can be replicated or added to a piece for use as "Reusable Content with pieces" this isn't working out like that at all!

I feel almost certain that this question will require further clarification of as it would seem I can't communicate well enough for the Apostrophe team for any of the questions I have posed so far!

Have I totally ignored something in the docs?
Why do I need to reload the page so often to make things act like they should?

I really like the general design, but I'm feeling slightly worried about the lack of basic question understanding and the general; oh we join to so many things its too complicated responses I see all over the web.

Comment: Hi Rob, would like to answer this question but as you say, it's a little vague as to how I can reproduce this situation.

Can you create a simple project that duplicates the issue? I understand that I might have to try something more than once in order to get to the error.

Thanks!

Comment: On a meta level, reviewing your questions, they all have a lot of comments and in some cases you've indicated success with the original issue and asked additional questions in comments. It would be easier to get to a resolution, and a question and answer that are more helpful to others, if you were to break things down just one question at a time.

Comment: Tom I can give you access to my admin interface if you email me Rmcglade@gm...l.com When you have some time to look at it.

Comment: In order for me to dig into your project code as a whole, we'd need to start an enterprise support relationship - which is great if you like, reach out to support at punkave dot com - or, if you can create a simpler project that can be shared here via a github link and some steps to duplicate the issue, then we can proceed without that and other community members may have insights as well of course.